# Convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<>'

Tags: c#, generics

In my model `Account` I have a property like this

```
public List<String> Roles { get; set; }
```

Later on I want to get that property but convert it `IList<IApplicationUserRole<Role>>`, so I have this function

```
 public IList<IApplicationUserRole<Role>> Roles
    {
        get
        {
            return _account.Roles; // how do I convert this in the specific type intended. 
        }
    }
```

Here is my IApplicationUserRole

```
public interface IApplicationUserRole<TRoleModel> : IRole<string>
    where TRoleModel : EntityModel
{
    TRoleModel Role { get; set; }

    String Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am a newbie to this thing. Looking forward for any help.

Comment: show us your `IApplicationUserRole`

Comment: Your problem is not how to convert from `List<T>` to `IList<T>`. That is not an issue. Your problem is that you have `IList<T>` (in the form of `List<T>`) but want to return `IList<U>`. You have to convert all the `T`'s to `U`'s.

Comment: @NiksonKantiPaul added that.

Comment: @MartinLiversage thanks mate. But can I get a more detail explanation? I am not following it actually.

Comment: The real problem is not the list-tytpes, but how you convert from one `string` to one `IApplicationUserRole<Role>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have your implementing class be something like:

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IApplicationUserRole<T> where T : Role
{
    public ApplicationUserRole()
    {
    }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public T Role { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you'd do something like this:

```
public IList<IApplicationUserRole<Role>> Roles
{
    get
    {
        return _account.Roles
            .Select(r => new ApplicationUserRole { Role = roleService.FindRoleByName(r) })
            .Cast<IApplicationUserRole<Role>>()
            .ToList(); 
    }
}
```

Where `roleService` is some way of building a `Role` instance from the role name (which above is `r`)

**NOTE**: This being said, there is a **catch** in the above implementation. Since `Roles` is a property it should not do data access operations. So, in this case, you should create a method instead of a property.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like this:

```
public IList<IApplicationUserRole<Role>> Roles
{
    get
    {
        return _account.Roles.Select(r=> 
               new ApplicationUserRole<Role>() {Name = r})
               .Cast<IApplicationUserRole<Role>>()
               .ToList(); 
    }
}
```

This assuming that you have a class that implements the `IApplicationUserRole<Role>` interface.

As @MartinLiversage says you can't directly convert `List<T>` to `List<U>`, you have to manually do the conversion.

Comment: This will not compile, you should cast the `ApplicationUserRole` to `IApplicationUserRole` in your LINQ expression.

Comment: Thanks @galenus but I already said "This assuming that you have a class that implements the `IApplicationUserRole<Role>` interface."

Comment: No, that was not my meaning. You return an instance of `List<ApplicationUserRole<Role>>` which is not compatible with `IList<IApplicationUserRole<Role>>` because `IList<T>` is not co-variant.

Comment: Thanks @galenus I've edited the answer!